# Python Validictory (JSON schema validation) constraints depending on value given with the JSON string

Tags: python, json, schema, validation

I am trying to create a JSON Schema validator which decides if one value is valid based on another in the given JSON

```
schema = {
"foo": {"type": "boolean"},
"bar": {
  "type": "object", "properties": {
    "measurements": 
      { "type": "object", "properties": {
        "x" : { "type": "number"}, #"required": "ONLY IF FOO is TRUE"
        "y" : { "type": "number"}
      }
  }
}
```

Is that somehow possible?

Comment: Have you had a look at the [schema](https://github.com/halst/schema) library?

Comment: @rantanplan: how would you do it?

Comment: Where I work we use https://github.com/podio/valideer, but it doesn't support validation based on the existence(or absence) of other attributes, so I rolled my own on top of it. You can try the one suggested by @zsquare and see if it does what you want. Otherwise you can just look at the source code of either library and try to implement that missing feature. In any case it will probably need hundreds of lines to show you how to do it and that makes for a very broad question. In addition, you haven't provided any source code, so I am not sure what kind of answer you're looking for.